# How do I find my windows 7 files?

Tags: windows, files, hidden-files

I have recently started using Ubuntu for the first time, and I can't seem to find my windows files. I've run a few searches and the answers say that I can find them by going to Filesystem > Users > MyName; however, when I go there, none of my files seem to exist. I restart my computer and boot using windows and it's all there. I would like to start using Ubuntu as I have heard many good things about using Linux over Windows, but if I can't access my files then I won't be able to.

I've done as mentioned below and on my other searches, and here is what I get:
 [image]

When I try as mentioned below, I see almost the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. It turns out the files were located in a different drive (For some reason my apparently 1TB drive is split into two, and one of them is virtually useless. The useless one was the one I could easily access) that I got to from FileSystem > Host > Users > etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you open your file browser you will see your windows disk at the top of the left pane.
Click on it and it is ready to use.

Answer (score 1):

Ok

Your problem is not related to Ubuntu. You don't know where are your files in Windows.

Actually, following folders are in your '*Documents and Settings*' folder:

- desktop
- download
- pictures
- videos
- ...

So you go to this address:

```
<<your drive (586 GB)> /Documents and Settings/ <your username> / Downloads
```

Then you will see your downloaded files there.

Comment: I followed those instructions, and that folder contains almost identical files and folders to what I found under "Users".

Answer (score 0):

Open your **Home Folder** (on top of your launcher, under Dash icon)
Then on left side of the window, you will see Devices on the top. These are all devices (all drives, CD, DVD, removable devices,...)
Then you will find your files

If you still have problem, let us know more detail about your problem.

Comment: I still have a problem, and I've updated the question.

Comment: don't go to Users folder. give me the list of folders in that drive. there should be one named _Documents and Settings_.  
share the screenshot from the drive (not Users folder)